# Camera 2 for older API? Is it possible?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera2, runtime-permissions

I want to create app by using camera2 but I want to support older API too. How do i do that? I can create using deprecated (old camera) to support latest device by targeting sdk22 but I want to ask camera permission. **Note:** I want it for flashlight application. Personally I don't need camera to open.

Answer (score 2):

Usually I wouldn't recommend a library for something that is a core OS feature, but the Camera/Camera2 APIs are a gigantic mess (that Google seems unlikely to fix).

[Try Fotoapparat](https://github.com/Fotoapparat/Fotoapparat): it has support for both Camera and Camera2 out of the box with no additional configuration required. It also does the heavy lifting of working around device specific bugs with the camera and provides a very nice API to work with.

Comment: actually I want to use for flashlight purpose

Comment: Fotoapparat supports flashlight, you just need to set torch() as the flash mode.

Comment: @ArjunThakuri - take a look at https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-cam2 also. As Eric says, Camera2 has a lot of edge case and race condition traps to navigate.